# Changing colour of buttons in tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter

While trying to make an elevator simulator I have come across a problem. 
There are 4 elevators and when the floor number is pressed it should change to be red. This works for 1 'panel' in 1 elevator, but not for 1 'panel' in each elevator. 
Here is my code :

```
def floorChooserButtons( self, eleNum, floors, yStart, yEnd, xStart, xEnd):
    self.Buttons1 = [i for i in range(41)]
    self.Buttons2 = [i for i in range(41)]
    self.Buttons3 = [i for i in range(41)]
    self.Buttons4 = [i for i in range(41)]
    if(eleNum is 1):
        xPos = xStart
        yPos = yStart
        for floor in floors:
            if(yPos == yEnd):
                xPos = xPos + 1
                yPos = yStart
            if(xPos == xEnd-1):
                yPos = yStart+2
            self.Buttons1[floor] = tk.Button(self, width=3, text=floor, 
                command = lambda f=floor: self.chooser(f, eleNum))
            self.Buttons1[floor].grid(row=xPos, column =yPos)
            yPos = yPos + 1
    elif(eleNum is 2):
        xPos = xStart
        yPos = yStart
        for floor in floors:
            if(yPos == yEnd):
                xPos = xPos + 1
                yPos = yStart
            if(xPos == xEnd-1):
                yPos = yStart+2
            self.Buttons2[floor] = tk.Button(self, width=3, text=floor, 
                command = lambda f=floor: self.chooser(f, eleNum))
            self.Buttons2[floor].grid(row=xPos, column =yPos)
            yPos = yPos + 1
    elif(eleNum is 3):
        xPos = xStart
        yPos = yStart
        for floor in floors:
            if(yPos == yEnd):
                xPos = xPos + 1
                yPos = yStart
            if(xPos == xEnd-1):
                yPos = yStart+2
            self.Buttons3[floor] = tk.Button(self, width=3, text=floor, 
                command = lambda f=floor: self.chooser(f, eleNum))
            self.Buttons3[floor].grid(row=xPos, column =yPos)
            yPos = yPos + 1
    elif(eleNum is 4):
        xPos = xStart
        yPos = yStart
        for floor in floors:
            if(yPos == yEnd):
                xPos = xPos + 1
                yPos = yStart
            if(xPos == xEnd-1):
                yPos = yStart+2
            self.Buttons4[floor] = tk.Button(self, width=3, text=floor, 
                command = lambda f=floor: self.chooser(f, eleNum))
            self.Buttons4[floor].grid(row=xPos, column =yPos)
            yPos = yPos + 1
        self.QUIT = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
            command=root.destroy).grid(row = xPos, column = yPos)


def chooser(self, index, eleNum):
    print("Number", index, "pressed in elevator", eleNum)
    if eleNum is 1:
        self.Buttons1[index].configure(bg="red")
    if eleNum is 2:
        self.Buttons2[index].configure(bg="red")
    if eleNum is 3:
        self.Buttons3[index].configure(bg="red")
    if eleNum is 4:
        self.Buttons4[index].configure(bg="red")
```

eleNum is the number of the elevator, it is 1-4
yStart, yEnd, xStart, xEnd are all used for the layout.

Any help would be smashing.
Thanks

Comment: This is misindented code.

Comment: @hd1 that is only due to stackoverflow, I have tried to indent it and its not allowing me to. It is properly indented in my code.

Comment: @MartynRushton: what do you mean it won't allow you? Of course it will. Replace all your tabs with spaces, insert your code, highlight it, and click on the `{}` button. If you expect people to put in effort to answer your question, you should put effort into asking it.

Comment: Okay, turns out I messed up with that...it is done right now =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the color of a button in many ways

```
b = Button(background = 'red')
b.config(background = 'red')
b.configure(background = 'red')
b['background'] = 'red'

b = Button(bg = 'red')
b.config(bg = 'red')
b.configure(bg = 'red')
b['bg'] = 'red'
```

You can change the font color with `foreground` or `fg`