# Changing the colour of a Tkinter button in a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I want to change the colour of a button when pressing a different button. The below code recreates the Attribrute Error.

Ideally the solution should be able to change all of the attributes of the button (see the attempted state change) but I didn't put this in the title because I don't know if 'attributes' is the right word.

```
import Tkinter

def tester():

    class window(Tkinter.Tk):
        def __init__(self,parent):
            Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
            self.parent = parent
            self.initialize()

        def initialize(self):
            self.grid()
            button1 = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Button")
            button1.grid(padx=5,pady=5)

            button2 = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Change",command=self.colourer)
            button2.grid(column=1,row=0,pady=5)  

            button3 = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Disabled",state='disabled')
            button3.grid(column=1,row=0,pady=5)                     

        def colourer(self):
            self.button1.configure(bg='red')
#           self.button1.config(bg='red')  -- this gives same error
#           self.button3.configure(state='normal')  -- as does this
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = window(None)
        app.title('Tester')
        app.mainloop()

tester()
```

All of the ways suggested here give the same error: [Changing colour of buttons in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458207/changing-colour-of-buttons-in-tkinter)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of your problem is that you're not defining `self.button`. You need to assign a value to that variable:

```
self.button = Tkinter.Button(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. you need give `self.button1` while `declaring`
2. if you see grid you gave same column name for button2 and button 3 so they overlap each other

try this

```
import Tkinter

def tester():

    class window(Tkinter.Tk):
        def __init__(self,parent):
            Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
            self.parent = parent
            self.initialize()

        def initialize(self):
            print self.grid()
            self.button1 = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Button")
            self.button1.grid(padx=5,pady=5)

            self.button2 = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Change",command=self.colourer)
            self.button2.grid(column=1,row=0,pady=5)

            self.button3 = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Disabled",state='disabled')
            self.button3.grid(column=2,row=0,pady=5)



        def colourer(self):
            self.button1.configure(bg='red')
#           self.button1.config(bg='red')  -- this gives same error
#           self.button3.configure(state='normal')  -- as does this
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = window(None)
        app.title('Tester')
        app.mainloop()

tester()
```

Comment: Thanks. Why does this work? I don't really understand classes and self.

Comment: @ElConfuso just rember this if you add self .variable it will accessable through out the methods of class if you dont give it. it thinks just local variable to that method

Comment: re: "yo uneed give self.button one while declaring". What does "one" refer to -- one color?